# Parse incomplete date with dateutil.parse

Tags: python, date

Is there a way to parse incomplete dates using the `dateutil` library without getting the current date or setting a default date?

```
dt = parser.parse(search, dayfirst=True).date()
```

For example parsing `10/02` would return `dt.month` = 02 and `dt.day` = 10. Is there a way to have it return `dt.year` = None or similar? Or to check beforehand that the date provided doesn't contain a year?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ...without getting the current date or setting a default date?

I assume you mean without getting the current **year**. The answer: no, it's not possible. `datetime.datetime` and `datetime.date` values **must** include an integer year. This is non-negotiable.

You can, of course, specify the year in your input, or change it afterwards:

```
from dateutil import parser

search = '10/02'
dt1 = parser.parse(search, dayfirst=True).date()            # datetime.date(2018, 2, 10)
dt2 = parser.parse(search + '/2017', dayfirst=True).date()  # datetime.date(2017, 2, 10)
dt1 = dt1.replace(year=2016)                                # datetime.date(2016, 2, 10)
```

> Or to check beforehand that the date provided doesn't contain a year?

I don't believe there's any functionality to check whether you've supplied a year in your string. You may have to write custom tests for this. `parser.parse` will work with what you have and try to fill in any gaps.